# Asking data to perform a lookup on itself generates a System Error?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

Apologies for the vague title - it's a bit of a tricky situation to describe.

So i have 2 data extensions: Auction and Bid.

When an auction is duplicated, it will have a new ID, but the copies over the same Group_ID as previous iterations. In theory, what i'm looking for is simple: find all bidders on *any* auction where Group ID matches an auction that's gone live in the past hour.

This is the code:

```
select
b.Bidder,
b.Email,
b.Auction, 
a.Id,
a.Group_ID,
a.Auction_Start_Date

from Bid b

inner join Auction a on a.Id = b.Auction

where a.Group_ID =

(select Group_ID
from Auction
WHERE Auction_Start_Date >= DATEADD(hh, -1, GETDATE())
)
```

Every time I run the above, I get the deaded **Automation failed due to system error**

Syntax is correct... so could someone point out where I'm going wrong?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use the `IN` operator for your sub-query and use an alias to remove the ambiguity:

```sql
select
  b.Bidder
, b.Email
, b.Auction 
, a.Id
, a.Group_ID
, a.Auction_Start_Date
from Bid b
inner join Auction a on a.Id = b.Auction
where a.Group_ID in  (
   select a0.Group_ID
   from Auction a0
   where a0.Auction_Start_Date >= DATEADD(hh, -1, GETDATE())
)
```

Comment: You're a star - thanks! That's fixed it.